# struct.error: bad char in struct format when i want to use struct.pack()

Tags: python, sockets, struct, pack

I want to pack my data to send it with socket.

I did it.

````
sensor = b'cam' 
msg = struct.pack('3s >I >I', sensor, len(channel), len(inf_bytes)) + channel + inf_bytes ```


And the I got: struct.error: bad char in struct format
Could you tell me where I am wrong?
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the first character in the format string can be > to use big-endian:

```
>>> struct.pack('3s>I>I', b'A', 2, 3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
struct.error: bad char in struct format

>>> struct.pack('>3sII', b'A', 2, 3)
b'A\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x03'
```

The doc says it: (emphasis mine)

> By default, C types are represented in the machine’s native format and byte order, and properly aligned by skipping pad bytes if necessary (according to the rules used by the C compiler).
> Alternatively, the **first character of the format string** can be used to indicate the byte order, size and alignment of the packed data, according to the following table:

at https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct-format-strings